# How do I solve this trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

L and H are known values, how do I get (solve) $RH$:

$RH * (1 – \cos ( \arctan(L/2 / RH ))) = H$

RH (not R*H) is circle radius

H is difference in beween radius and line crossing to circle.

L is length of line.

//edit

simply put, by replacing RH with R

$R * (1 – \cos ( \arctan(L/2 / R ))) = H$

Comment: What is L/2/RH? IS RH R*H or a variable RH?

Comment: is that $arctan\frac{\frac{L}{2}}{RH}$?

Comment: You might want to learn MathJax so that you can more easily explain your questions in the future.

Comment: @user1709828, ah; no RH is NOT R*H, please se elaboration

Comment: @JosephSkelton, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the trigonometric functions. In fact, $\cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Comment: Phytagoras - perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at a right-angled triangle to see if you can simplify $\cos(\arctan(x))$, then solve for RH.

If you have a right-angled triangle where one of the non-hypotenuse sides is $L/2/RH$, and the other non-hypotenuse side is $1$, which angle corresponds to $\arctan(L/2/RH)$, and therefore what is $\cos(\arctan(L/2/RH))$?

Comment: Yes, I belive You're right here. Think of a line crossing close ot border of a circle. H is the small (maximum) distance between the circle and line. L is the length of the line. I want the radius of the circle.

Comment: Suceeded in simplifying to: L = 2R * arctan((L/2) / (R-H)). Puzzled from here..

Comment: If you move the $2R$ over, you have $L / 2R = \arctan((L/2) / RH)$. How do you get rid of the $\arctan$?

Comment: The best I can come up with is L/2 / (R-H) = tan(L / 2R)

Comment: And you're solving for $RH$, where $L$ and $R$ are known, right?

Comment: H is known, (21), L known:1330, R unknown (15500).

Comment: Typo in OP, corrected, sorry..

Comment: Sorry, too late, you're perfectly right. Solving for "RH" (not R*H). Good night.